# Converting long to int gives 0

Tags: java, int, type-conversion, long-integer

I have been testing out with this snippet of code:

```
public class Test {
    public static int longToInt(long num) {
        return (int) (num);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(longToInt(100000000L));
    }
}
```

I ran it but longToInt only returned 0. What is going on?

Comment: Unable to reproduce: https://ideone.com/R4jZJ2

Comment: You get `int` overflow if your `long` value is larger than `int` can handle.

Comment: What version of Java? When I run your code I get `1215752192`

Comment: It is working fine for me

Comment: Does "Hello World" work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting a `long` to an `int` is done by removing the top 32 bits of the `long`.  If the `long` value is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2147483647) or smaller than `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (-2147483648), the net effect is that you lose significant bits, and the result is "rubbish".

---

Having said that, the code you supplied does not behave like you say it does ... if you compile and run it correctly.  The original version should print an unexpected number ... but not zero.  The modified version should print 1000000 as expected.

---

> ... is there a way I can store a long number larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE inside an int number?

No.

Well strictly yes ... in some circumstances.  You could do something to map the numbers,  For example, if you know that your numbers are always in the range `A` to `B`, and `B - A` is less than 2<sup>32</sup>, then you could map a `long` in that range to an `int` by subtracting `A` from it.

However, it is mathematically **impossible** to define such a mapping if the size of the domain of numbers you are storing in the `long` is larger than 2<sup>32</sup>.  Which it typically is.

Comment: I think it was some other mistake...Having said that, is there a way I can store a long number larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE inside an int number?

Comment: I wouldn't call the number *unexpected*.

Comment: @ChristianHujer - it is unexpected by the OP.  That who this answer is primarily addressed to.  (I didn't say "unpredictable" or "random" ... both of which would really have been wrong!)

Comment: You can treat the int as unsigned, but you can only store 2^32 distinct values.

Comment: @StephenC You're right and already got my upvote. Just saying that once you know what's going on it's not unexpected. Unexpected are things which are inconsistent, not logical or bugs. But you already got my upvote, I'm just being very pedantic on wording right now, and you may ignore that if you like :)

Answer (score 1):

because, the long you gave doesn't fit into int. Give a smaller long and try !
int (32 bits)
long (64 bits)

Comment: Actually `100000000L` *does* fit into an `int.`